# Karma not pausing in debugger mode

Tags: javascript, gulp, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run my application in Chrome using Karma. I configured karma.conf.js in such a way where I would expect the browser to run through all tests and then not exit: I have set this up with other projects and that is what occurs. However, on this project the browser always exits as soon as tests are finished and this prevents me from debugging.

**Karma.config.js**

```
   module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '.',


    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [ 'dist/appTest.js', 'dist/app.css' ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [

    ],


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
    reporters: ['mocha', 'junit'],

    junitReporter: {
        outputDir: '', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
        outputFile: undefined, // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
        suite: '' // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
    },

    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera (has to be installed with `npm install karma-opera-launcher`)
    // - Safari (only Mac; has to be installed with `npm install karma-safari-launcher`)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows; has to be installed with `npm install karma-ie-launcher`)
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
    captureTimeout: 60000,


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you hit the Debug button on the Karma server page, and then set breakpoints using the Chrome dev console?

Comment: Yeah, it pauses for a few seconds and then just exits the tests